# One-way functions and P=NP

Tags: one-way-function

This site contains various [discussions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39878/how-to-show-that-a-one-way-function-proves-that-p-%E2%89%A0-np) of one-way functions and their relation to P versus NP.

Some of these discussions use a language 
$L=\{(x',y) ~\mid~ x'\le x \text{ and } f(x)=y \}$, where $f:\Sigma^*\to\Sigma^*$ is the one-way function and $x'\le x$ is the prefix relation.
Now one central claim is that this language $L$ is contained in NP, since the word $x$ is a YES-certificate for $(x',y)\in L$.

I do not see why this claim is justified.
Why is the length of the certificate $x$ polynomially bounded in the length of $(x',y)$?

Couldn't it be possible that $x$ is exponentially long in $y$ and $x'$, but $f(x)$ is short and quickly computable from $x$?

Comment: It is likely that a proof that P=NP is not an effective proof. Crypto works about the same if the effort to crack n bit keys is 2^n or n^65536.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it could be that in the language you give, $x$ is exponentially long in $(y,x')$, and $f$ is an efficiently computable one-way function (note that it only has to run in time polynomial in its input length, so $f(x)$ needs not be computable in time polynomial in $(y,x')$).

However, this is really a minor issue: the answers to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39878/how-to-show-that-a-one-way-function-proves-that-p-%E2%89%A0-np) that you read are simply a bit informal, and only give an intuition of the proof that OWF implies $P \neq NP$. Intuitively, to fix this, modify your language as follows:

$L=\{(1^n, x',y) ~\mid~ \exists x, |x| = n, x'\le x, \text{ and } f(x)=y \}$,

where $1^n$ means a sequence of $n$ consecutive one, which exactly allows to fix the issue you point out (note that here $x'\le x$ means $x'$ is a prefix of $x$).

Note: the second answer to the question you link to does provide a link to an [exercise sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506203837/https://courses.cs.ut.ee/all/MTAT.07.004/2016_fall/uploads/solution/solution-11.pdf) which contains the more formal solution.

Comment: Sorry, but with your modification it is not clear anymore how to invert function $f$ in polynomial time, in case $L$ is in $P$.  For exploting $L$, it seems that now I need some a priori bound on $n$, but this might be exponentially large in the length of $y$.

Comment: Inverting $f$ needs not be polynomial in the *output size* $y$, but still in the *input size* $x$, which is the case if $L$ is in $P$. You should check the detailed solution given on page 2-3 of the exercise sheet I link to (https://courses.cs.ut.ee/all/MTAT.07.004/2016_fall/uploads/solution/solution-11.pdf).

Comment: With polynomial runtime for *f* you can not generate an output *f(x)* with superpolynonial size - so actually any limitation on *x* also translates to *y* implicitly.